# Slow Google Analytics Data API (GA4) request

Tags: php, performance, google-analytics-api

I'm displaying custom data dashboard with the new Google Analytics Data API (GA4).

The request output is correct but really slow..

```
require './vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DateRange;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Dimension;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Metric;


        putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=1_cms_main_conf/google_service_account.json');


        $property_id = $conf['idAnalytics'];
        $client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();


        $dailyStat = $client->runReport([
            'property' => 'properties/' . $property_id,
            'dateRanges' => [
                new DateRange([
                    'start_date' => '20daysAgo',
                    'end_date' => 'yesterday',
                ]),
            ],
            'dimensions' => [
                new Dimension(['name' => 'date',]),
            ],
            'metrics' => [
                new Metric(['name' => 'activeUsers',]),
                new Metric(['name' => 'newUsers',]),
            ]
        ]);

    }
```

I'm currently saving the return in a file so I can display it faster, but the first day call remain a pain.

- Am I missing something ?
- Is my request correct or missing some lightening params ?
- This new APi is still in beta, is this loading time "normal" and temporary ?
- Did this API build only for serveur side call like CRON job and not for page loaded directly by client ?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing this is a beta api.
At the time of writing this is also a free api.

Speed with regard to Google apis is always a question.  Your script will run as fast as googles servers allow there is nothing inherently wrong with your code you are being limited on googles end. It both takes time to process your request and time to return it to you.  There is no way for you to know what is going on on the server at the time you send the request.

As there is really nothing you can do other than requesting less data, fewer dimensions and metrics over a shorter period of time.

Comment: 2 years later - still a beta API.

Comment: It will be for a while yet they are still working on it